# Log file in Append Mode

Tags: log

I am running a process which is generating a log file in Write mode. Obviously > or cat /dev/null won't work as the file handlers are open ...

Is there any way to truncate the log file without having to restart the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Appending to a file is basic in any language. What exactly do you mean by "file handlers are open", and why are they? Writing or appending to a file is a single action with a beginning and an end.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I didn't make myself very clear. I am running a process on my server which is writing a log file in "Write Mode". It seems the process was badly designed because the log size is becoming huge and the only way to truncate it is by restarting the process and "releasing" the open log file. If the log file was being written in "Append Mode" a simple "> log.file" would solve the problem but this is not the case. My question is: considering the log file is open in "Write" Mode, is there any way to truncate the file without bouncing the process?